# How do i fix image not displaying in github pages?

Tags: html, github-pages

Please I need help with my Github page. There is an image that will not show and I have tried my best, I don’t know why I can’t figure. Any help would be appreciated. @ Portfolio|Editoro Please check/inspect the “About me” section. https://eddyah5.github.io/Portfolio/. Also see attached, the first image below shows the result of running the page locally on my PC and the second image shows when I run it on Github as Github pages. Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `/` before img :

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/about1.jpg" align="">
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom  you rock ! 